# Need to find out the average of an array

Tags: javascript

```js
function average(arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var total = 0;
    total += arr[i]
  }
  return total / arr.length;
}

console.log(average([74, 55, 6, 35]));
```

It gives back the answer 8.75?
i cant see what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: move `var total = 0;` outside of the loop. it assigns zero at every loop. the `var`/declaration is hoisted. btw, declare all variables.

Comment: `total` should be declared outside the loop body and you probably want to declare `i` using `let` or `var`

Comment: Understood thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you iterate you are reassigning total to 0. Move it outside of the loop.

```
function average(arr) {
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total += arr[i]
  }
  return total / arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const average = (arr) => {
  let total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total += arr[i]
  }
  return total / arr.length;
}

console.log(average([74, 55, 6, 35]));
```